# Google map embed code does not work

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-embed

I am trying to embed a map using the code supplied by Google Maps with no alterations. When the page is displayed the Google pointer, zoom level indicator, etc. show but no streets or map, per se. This is the code Google suppled:

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hl=en&amp;cd=2&amp;ei=Gh10TNbbGZj0ygTT24nwCQ&amp;sig2=hvRb-F6JuV91UcC6QUKGUw&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=16713672426408470324&amp;ved=0CBoQpQY&amp;hq=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=34.986955,-84.368584&amp;spn=0.006153,0.013754&amp;z=16&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near&amp;addr"></iframe>
    <br />
    <small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hl=en&amp;cd=2&amp;ei=Gh10TNbbGZj0ygTT24nwCQ&amp;sig2=hvRb-F6JuV91UcC6QUKGUw&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=16713672426408470324&amp;ved=0CBoQpQY&amp;hq=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=34.986955,-84.368584&amp;spn=0.006153,0.013754&amp;z=16&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small></div>
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to embed a Google map into your page, or just create a link to the Google Maps website?  Because what you have there is not an embedded map but rather just a link to the Google Maps site.

Comment: Never mind, you didn't use code formatting so your actual embed code was hidden.  I edited your question to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It works on my machine.

Maybe you forgot to add the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. You also have a closing `</div>` that doesn't start anywhere, but it should nevertheless work even without its opening tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" marginheight="0"
            marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hl=en&amp;cd=2&amp;ei=Gh10TNbbGZj0ygTT24nwCQ&amp;sig2=hvRb-F6JuV91UcC6QUKGUw&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=16713672426408470324&amp;ved=0CBoQpQY&amp;hq=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=34.986955,-84.368584&amp;spn=0.006153,0.013754&amp;z=16&amp;output=embed&amp;iwloc=near&amp;addr">
        </iframe>
        <br />
        <small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hl=en&amp;cd=2&amp;ei=Gh10TNbbGZj0ygTT24nwCQ&amp;sig2=hvRb-F6JuV91UcC6QUKGUw&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;view=map&amp;cid=16713672426408470324&amp;ved=0CBoQpQY&amp;hq=First+Baptist+Church,+Mc+Caysville,+GA+30555&amp;hnear=&amp;ll=34.986955,-84.368584&amp;spn=0.006153,0.013754&amp;z=16&amp;source=embed"
            style="color: #0000FF; text-align: left">View Larger Map</a></small></div>
</body>
</html>
```